# Best approach for one to many in EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many

I'd like to ask you guys, what's the difference between this two approaches.

**Scenario 1**

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

In both cases, EF will generate tables with proper columns and foreign keys. So, is it one scenario better than another?

Sorry for my english and thanks for your help :)

Comment: 'Difference' in what sense? You added `virtual` in the second scenario and that's definitely a difference, but probably not the difference you're asking about

Comment: #1 won't work with `public Bar Bar { get; set; }` and without `public int BarId { get; set; }`

Comment: Oh yes, I should check that firts. But this works in first scenario `public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }` and without `public int BarId { get; set; }`

Comment: Here's some background reading on foreign keys  Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx and Making Do with Absent Foreign Keys http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not better or worse.

The EDM model deducted from your Code First is quite similar (perhaps equal) in both cases.

However there is a very important difference: in the second case you have access to several things that are missing in the first one:

- the `BarId` in `Foo`
- the `Foos` in `Bar`

Appart from this difference the in-memory EDM model, and the behavior of queries made against the model will be the same.

SO the only question is: do you need to access the `Foos` from the `Bar`? Do you need to access the `BarId` in the `Foo`? That's the only real difference.

Comment: Thank you JotaBe! I just wanted to make sure that this work the same way.